# Tables trouble. I need help to make them

Tags: java

I want to make a list going to n numbers depending on user input. I then want to put a second number in each place and print the entire table. As for testing I have tried with a length 4 and numbers 1,2,3,4 but I get a error: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. I wanted it to print 1,2,3,4.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);   

System.out.println("Whats the length of the table?");
int lengde = keyboard.nextInt();                   

int[] minTabell = new int[lengde]; 

for (int i =1; i <= lengde+ 1; i++) {
  System.out.println((i) + (" give a number"));
  minTabell[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
}

System.out.println(minTabell);


keyboard.close();
```

Comment: Your for loops should start counter at 0 (first element). IE: for (int i = 0; i < lengde; i++) { ... }

Comment: Word you are looking for is "array". Also their indexes start from 0, not 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes in Java arrays are 0-based, while your for-loop starts from 1. So,

```
for (int i =1; i <= lengde+ 1; i++) {
  System.out.println((i) + (" give a number"));
  minTabell[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

should be

```
for (int i =0; i < lengde; i++) {
//          ^    ^^^^^^^^
  System.out.println((i+1) + (" give a number"));
//                    ^^^
  minTabell[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

As for printing the content of the array, I suggest you use

```
for (int i : minTabell)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java array indexing starts at 0. The first element is positioned at minTabel1[0]. Your for-loop runs from 1 to lengde + 1, which means that you will try to fill a position outside of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The first element of an array has the index 0. The last valid index of your array is `lengde-1`.

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i < lengde; i++) {
    System.out.println((i) + (" give a number"));
    minTabell[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

To print the array, i suggest the following:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(minTabell));
```

Comment: Thanx, the for loop is fixed, but I get message saying Arrays can not be resolved?

Comment: import java.util.Arrays;